# Framer Motion AnimatePresence Nested Import Problem

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

It would appear I've hit a peculiar problem with **Framer Motion and it's exitBeforeEnter tag** with regards to importing components that have the `motion.div` attribute.

The following works as intended:

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter> 
<div>
    <CoverImageComp var={blah} var={blah}/>
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      {!editing ? (
        <EditorComp key={router.pathname}/>
      :
        <PreviewComp key={router.pathname+'-preview'}/>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>

</div>
</AnimatePresence>
```

However if I was to place the `CoverImageComp` into the !editing ternary operator than the exit animate breaks - with the whole page moving onto the next (via an onClick event)

```
    !editing ? (
        <>
         <CoverImageComp var={blah} var={blah}/>
         <EditorComp key={router.pathname}/>
        </>
    ): ...
```

**The above doesn't appear to work**, my first assumption was to add a unique key to the `CoverImageComp` much like `router.pathname+'-cover'`. I've also tried wrapping the editing blocks with a `AnimatePresence` which also didn't provide the desired outcome.

It's also worth nothing the imported components have the following motion tags attached to their container divs:

```
<motion.div
   variants={{
    initial: {
        x: '500px',
    },
    animate: {
        x: '0px',
    },
    exit: {
        x: '500px',
    },
    }}
    initial={'initial'}
    animate={'animate'}
    exit={'exit'}
    transition={{
        type: 'spring', mass: 0.35, stiffness: 45,
    }}
    className={styles.editor_form}
>
```

I am sure I'm following the directions laid out in Framer's API but I must be missing something!? Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

```
  !editing ? (
        <>
         <CoverImageComp var={blah} var={blah}/>
         <EditorComp key={router.pathname}/>
        </>
    ): ...
```

To

```
  !editing ? (
        <React.Fragment key={router.pathname}>
         <CoverImageComp var={blah} var={blah}/>
         <EditorComp />
        </React.Fragment>
    ): ...
```

I know it feels weird but the <> is sugar for  or <React.Fragment /> depending on how you export. Like other components they need a key for framer to know if they change or not.

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments